# Graph Isomerism and Isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory

Two graphs $G$ and $G^{\prime}$ are said to be *graph isomeric* if the share the same number of vertices and edges. If there is a graph homomorphism $h \colon G \to G^{\prime}$ between graph isomers which preserves vertex degree, can one conclude that $G$ and $G^{\prime}$ are graph isomorphic?

Comment: I never know what people's conventions for graph homomorphisms are. Are they just maps from vertices to vertices that preserve the relation given by edges? Are vertices considered related to themselves for the purposes of this relation?

Comment: I'm using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism) definition of homomorphism.

Answer (score 5):

$$1-2-1 \quad 1-2-1$$

is not isomorphic with
$$1-1 \quad 1-2-2-1$$

But they are isomeric and there is a trivial homomorphism. There are plenty of other examples...

Comment: Sorry, what is the homomorphism which preserves vertex degrees?

Comment: just the 2's onto the 2's and the 1's onto the 1's

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't understand how you were mapping the vertices of degree $1$ but it is clear now.

Comment: What if we add "connected" to the assumptions?

Comment: 2-3-2 and 3-2-2, just complete with 1s where needed...